# How does FragmentPagerAdapter manage views in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I use a FragmentPagerAdapter in my app. When I switch between different tabs, I want to update the fragment view.

I tried as following, however, the view in the fragment is null and I can not update it when tab is switched. Then, how can I update the fragment view?

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
        public void onPageSelected(int position){

            //
            if(position == 1){
                DownloadFragment fragment = (DownloadFragment) adapter.getItem(position);
                fragment.onRefresh(MainActivity.this);
            }

            getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is move your update code to the fragment itself. When it is shown in the `ViewPager`the method `public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` on the fragment gets called by the `ViewPager`. You can update your fragment in there.